# Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined error in salesforce lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service, salesfoce

I am having this error while running lightning component from preview. Locker service has been enabled recently.

[image]

below are the codes,

### component

```
<aura:component controller="ReportController">
    <!-- Load external scripts/styles -->
    <ltng:require styles="/resource/slds080/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css" />
    <!--<ltng:require scripts="/resource/mf_util" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}"/>-->

    <!-- Register event handlers -->
    <aura:registerEvent name="componentException" type="c:componentException"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"></aura:handler>

    <!-- External attributes -->
    <aura:attribute name="titleLabel" type="String" description="External. API name of the Custom Label containing the chart's title text."></aura:attribute>
    <aura:attribute name="decimalPlaces" type="Integer" default="0" description="External. Number of decimal places to show. Trailing 0's will only be shown for currency values."></aura:attribute>
    <aura:attribute name="queries" type="Object[]" description="External. Array of objects representing SOQL queries used to grab data."></aura:attribute>
    <aura:attribute name="monthsToShow" type="Integer" default="7"></aura:attribute>

    <!-- Internal attributes -->
    <aura:attribute name="results" type="Object[]" description="Internal. Array of results from executing the SOQL queries in 'queries.'"></aura:attribute>
    <aura:attribute name="title" type="String" description="Internal. The value of the Custom Label defined in 'titleLabel.'"></aura:attribute>
    <aura:attribute name="intervalId" type="String" description="Internal. The ID of the interval used to periodically check if the dynamically accessed labels are loaded."></aura:attribute>
    <aura:attribute name="detailHeaders" type="String[]" description="Internal. Array of headers for the table."></aura:attribute>
    <aura:attribute name="detailRows" type="Object[]" description="Internal. Array of rows containing values for the table."></aura:attribute>
    <aura:attribute name="cseFilter" type="String[]"></aura:attribute>
    <aura:attribute name="idnFilter" type="String[]"></aura:attribute>
    <aura:attribute name="accountFilter" type="String[]"></aura:attribute>
    <aura:attribute name="isLocal" type="Boolean" default="false" description="Internal. Indicates whether the query fields have a Local__c in them."></aura:attribute>
    <aura:attribute name="divisionMap" type="Object" description="Internal. Object containing the table row results of all the data and calculations by BU and division."></aura:attribute>

    <div class="loading-wrap">
        <div aura:id="spinner" class="loading slds-hide">
            <img class="slds-spinner--large" src="/resource/slds080/assets/images/spinners/slds_spinner_brand.gif" alt="Loading..." />
        </div>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <div class="slds-text-align--center">
        <div class="slds-text-heading--small">Trends by Product Line</div>
        </div>        
       <c:SelectorCSE isLocal="true" filterChanged="c.filterChanged"/>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--1-of-2 slds-p-around--small">
                <div class="slds-form-element">
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label">{!$Label.c.MF_Wakeup_SelectFieldv2}</label>
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <ui:inputSelect aura:id="selectField" change="{!c.fieldChanged}">
                            <ui:inputSelectOption text="sales" label="{!$Label.c.MF_Wakeup_OptionRevenue}"></ui:inputSelectOption>
                            <ui:inputSelectOption text="units" label="{!$Label.c.MF_Wakeup_OptionUnits}"></ui:inputSelectOption>
                            <ui:inputSelectOption text="asp" label="{!$Label.c.MF_Wakeup_OptionASP}"></ui:inputSelectOption>
                        </ui:inputSelect>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--1-of-2 slds-p-around--small">
                <div class="slds-form-element">
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label">{!$Label.c.MF_Wakeup_SelectPeriod}</label>
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <ui:inputSelect aura:id="selectPeriod" change="{!c.periodChanged}">
                            <ui:inputSelectOption text="months" label="{!$Label.c.MF_Wakeup_OptionMonths}"></ui:inputSelectOption>
                            <ui:inputSelectOption text="quarters" label="{!$Label.c.MF_Wakeup_OptionQuarters}"></ui:inputSelectOption>
                        </ui:inputSelect>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <c:DataTable title="Trends by Product Line" shrinkTitle="true" headers="{!v.detailHeaders}" rows="{!v.detailRows}" responseMode="stack"></c:DataTable>
        <br/><br/><br/>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

### controller :

```
({ 

    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        window.alert('entry into init');
        var titleLabel = component.get('v.titleLabel');
        console.log(titleLabel + ' Init');

        var intervalId = window.setInterval(function(cmp, a) {
            console.log('terr table label check');
            //keep trying to load label every half second
            var labelA = $A.get('$Label.c.' + a);
            //check if labels are all loaded
            if(labelA !== '[c.' + a + ']' && labelA.length) {
                cmp.set('v.title', labelA);
                window.clearInterval(cmp.get('v.intervalId'));
            }
        }, 1000, component, titleLabel);
        component.set('v.intervalId', intervalId);

        var i, j, isLocal = false;
        var queries = component.get('v.queries');
        for(i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < queries[i].fields.length; j++) {
                if(queries[i].fields[j].indexOf('Local__c') > 0) {
                    isLocal = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        component.set('v.isLocal', isLocal);
        window.alert('exit before helper');
        helper.getQueryResults(component);
        window.alert('exit after helper');
    },
    filterChanged : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.applyFilters(component, event);
    },
    fieldChanged : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.buildTable(component);
    },
    periodChanged : function(component, event, helper) {
        var queries = component.get('v.queries');
        var selected = component.find('selectPeriod').get('v.value');
        console.log('selected: ' + selected);

        var i, j;
        //only need to change the second query (months)
        if(selected === 'months') {
            //2nd query contains the months
            if(queries.length && queries.length > 1) {
                console.log('change to months');
                for(i = 0; i < queries[1].fields.length; i++) {
                    queries[1].fields[i] = queries[1].fields[i].replace('FISCAL_QUARTER', 'CALENDAR_MONTH');
                }

                for(i = 0; i < queries[1].filters.length; i++) {
                    queries[1].filters[i] = queries[1].filters[i].replace('LAST_N_FISCAL_QUARTERS', 'LAST_N_MONTHS').replace('THIS_FISCAL_QUARTER', 'THIS_MONTH');
                }
            }
        }
        else if(selected === 'quarters') {
            console.log('change to quarters');
            for(i = 0; i < queries[1].fields.length; i++) {
                queries[1].fields[i] = queries[1].fields[i].replace('CALENDAR_MONTH', 'FISCAL_QUARTER');
            }

            for(i = 0; i < queries[1].filters.length; i++) {
                queries[1].filters[i] = queries[1].filters[i].replace('LAST_N_MONTHS', 'LAST_N_FISCAL_QUARTERS').replace('THIS_MONTH', 'THIS_FISCAL_QUARTER');
            }
        }

        console.log('changed queries:');
        console.log(queries);

        component.set('v.queries', queries);
        helper.getQueryResults(component);
    }
})
```

Comment: You should try running Lightning CLI on your code, if there is any typo it will let you know: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/cli_intro.htm

Comment: Google how to get your browser to breakpoint when an exception happens and work back from that breakpoint.

Answer (score 3):

I can see error at below line,

```
window.setInterval(function(cmp, a)
```

It should be,

```
window.setInterval(function(component, a)
```

Comment: Not sure the var name matters in this case as the calling js is simply passing the values in.